# Storage data from StreamBuilder

Tags: sqlite, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make an app like WhatsApp by using Firestore, I've a problem when I receive the data from `StreamBuilder` every time I scroll to status or close the app the stream rebuild chats again.

The question is how can I store the data " chats " from stream to put it again in `InitialData` for `StreamBuilder` ?

I guess through `SQLite` but is there any other way ?

Comment: does your app's data continuously changing ?

Comment: Yup .. like whatsapp

Comment: Then enable firebase offline persistence it saves your data and displays if there’s no new data available, since widgets can rebuild at anytime its ideal to control it.

Comment: Can you provide me a document or the away to do that ?.

Comment: okay @Ahmed I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be resolved by making firebase offline persistent, run this code below usually in your main class.

```
  void setDatabasePersistent() {
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
    database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    database.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(10000000);

  }
```